# Image not uploading in storage laravel livewire, returning 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel Jetstream livewire, Everything is working fine on localhost. But when I am uploading profile picture online, It's path is saving in database `'/storage/profile-photos/pJis4kArzwPH059sisxUvVR95h81UI8EFXm1pRrV.jpg'` but image is broken and returning `404 not found` .

I tried everything ie:

```
    $exitCode = \Artisan::call('config:cache');
    $exitCode = \Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = \Artisan::call('view:clear');
    $exitCode = \Artisan::call('route:clear');
    $exitCode = \Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
    $exitCode  = \Artisan::call('storage:link');
```

But nothing worked.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Is the storage linked? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: yes I run link command as well as \Artisan::call('storage:link'); on server

Comment: But the question if it actually succeeded linking the folders. Check your `public` folder, is there a "shortcut" to the storage folder?

Comment: there is storage folder in public, not shortcut